# Is there an iterative procedure that pushes the singular values of a matrix toward unity?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

Consider a square matrix $A = U \Sigma V^T$.  I want to find $B = UV^T$ — however, it seems wasteful to compute the whole SVD just to re-multiply the two orthogonal matrices.

Does there exist some stable procedure I can use to "push" the entries in the diagonal matrix $\Sigma$ toward ones?

Comment: A related question is discussed in the paper "[Parameter selection and preconditioning for a graph form solver](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pogs.html)" by Fougner and Boyd at Stanford.

Comment: I doubt that it is possible. Because, To calculate SVD, first one usually finds the diagonal matrix and $U$. $V$ is found such that $A=UDV^T$. Remember that $U$ and $V$ are not unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $A_0=A$ and $A_n = (1/2)(A_{n-1}+(A_{n-1}^T)^{-1})$. I claim $A_n \to UV$, and does so rapidly.

Define $f(x) = \frac{x+x^{-1}}{2}$. Suppose $A=UDV$ where the diagonal entries of $D$ are $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, ..., $\sigma_k>0$. Then induction shows that $A_n = U D_n V$ where $D$ is diagonal with entries $f^{(n)}(\sigma_j)$. (Here $f^{(n)}$ means iterate $f$ for $n$ times.) For any $\sigma>0$, $f^{(n)}(\sigma) \to 1$, and does so quite rapidly: $|f^{(n)}(\sigma)-1|$ shrinks like $1/\exp(c \cdot 2^n)$.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this method.

Comment: It is called Heron's method. It can be [refined to speed up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Numerical_determination_of_the_matrix_polar_decomposition). Similar method by Halley (the same link) can be applied to rectangular matrices too.

Comment: @A.G. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

David , 1. Note that $x\rightarrow (x+1/x)/2$ is the Newton iteration for the calculation of an approximation of $\sqrt{1}$. If $\sigma =1000\approx 2^{10}$, one needs more that $10$ iterations.

2. What is the interest ? Each matricial iteration has complexity $\sim n^3$; compare with the cost of the calculation of the SVD (in $O(n^3)$) and the multiplication $UV^T$ ($\sim n^3$).
3. The OP assumes (if I correctly understand his question) that the singular values are unknown. How do you write your iteration ? Anyway, the calculation of the singular values is also in $O(n^3)$.
4. The couple $U,V$ is not unique but I think that $UV^T$ is unique.

Comment: Regarding 3: I'm iterating the recursion $A_0 = A$, $A_{n+1} = (1/2) (A_n + (A_n^T)^{-1})$. There is no step at which I explicitly compute the SVD. I simply use the fact that the SVD exists to show why this recursion has the convergence properties it does.

Comment: Regarding 2: Basic order of magnitude complexity analysis gives $O(n^3)$ for both methods, so the question is presumably about actual constants and numerical stability. I'm not an expert enough on this subject to know which is better, but the fact that this turned out to be a named method for doing SVD suggests it is not terrible.

Comment: I'm not sure why the OP wanted an iterative procedure of this sort. One reason might be that his or her singular values are all very close to equal (for example, because the input is nearly orthgonal.) In that case, computing the precise matrices $U$ and $V$ will be numerically unstable, while $U V^T$ will be stable, and I would guess that this method should be better since it never goes through the computation of $U$ and $V$.

Comment: @ David Speyer , of course, I agree with your comments. Some remarks: For your 1. OK, each step has complexity $\sim n^3$. For your 2. Indeed the question is about the constants. To calculate the eigenvalues of a generic matrix is at least $\sim 20n^3$. Yet, when the matrix is symmetric, I think that the complexity is lower. For your 3. I think that it is you best argument.  On the other hand, if we consider on $M_n$ the standard inner product $tr(K^TL)$, then when $A$ is invertible, $UV$ is the "orthogonal projection" of $A$ on $O(n)$.